# how can i display the decrypted password in gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, hash, passwords

I have hashed my password in my `registration.aspx` page and manage to log in through it. However, I have this `viewprofile.aspx` page wherein it will display all of the customer details in a `FormView` along  including the password. My problem is how can i make the decrypted password show in the `FormView` in the password column? To make this clear, this is what i got so far from my `viewprofile.aspx` page:

```
private void bindgrid()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    dt = new DataTable();
    com.Connection = conn;
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE Username ='" + Session["New"] + "'";
    sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    sqlda.Fill(dt);
    EmployeeFormView.DataSource = dt;
    EmployeeFormView.DataBind();
}
```

Given the code above, it gives me all of the details perfectly fine but also gets the hashed(encrypted) password. any idea or trick that you can share on how will I manage to this?

Here is my business layer page where the hash code is:

```
public static string CreateSHAHash(string Phrase)
{
    SHA512Managed HashTool = new SHA512Managed();
    Byte[] PhraseAsByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Phrase));
    Byte[] EncryptedBytes = HashTool.ComputeHash(PhraseAsByte);
    HashTool.Clear();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
}
```

here is my `registration` page code as well where it shows the hashing of the password:

```
protected void btn_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string insertQuery = "insert into UserData(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password,CustomerType,DeliveryAddress,Zip,ContactNumber)values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";
        SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPW.Text));
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
        scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);

        scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        txtUser.Text = "";
        txtFN.Text = "";
        txtLN.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtAddress.Text = "";
        txtZip.Text = "";
        txtContact.Text = "";
        label_register_success.Text = ("Registration Successful!");
        conn.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hashing is only one way. You can't unhash a string.

Answer (score 1):

Password are hashed and afterwards saved to the Repository and can not be reversed.

- [Hash Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) - One way.
- [Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) - Two ways.

**Trivial Process:**

**Register**

1. `Username` and `Password` are sent.
2. New Repository record is inserted with `Username` and `Hashed Password`

**Login**

1. `Username` and `Password` is sent to the server.
2. Server is hashing the given `Password`.
3. Server than checking whatever the chosen `Username` repository `Password`is equals to the `Hashed Password` that has been sent.
4. Cookies are formed and a new journey take place.

Comment: ohhh so theres no way :( @Orel Eraki